# Как это работает vk.com/id***, ask.fm/*username*??

Tags: php

Как сделать отдельную страничку для каждого пользователя на сайте? Например mysite.ru/vasiya? Раньше я делал типа: .../user.php?id=vasiya. Как сделать аля контакт?) это трюк с htmlaccess? не может же быть что для каждого пользователя отдельный файл....
заранее спасибо!

Comment: 127.0.0.1/trol  = 127.0.0.1/user.php?id=trol
=>
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ user.php?id=$1

Comment: С помощью mod_rewrite происходит преобразование адресов запроса к серверу.  
Например все что стоит после id будет передаваться как параметр другому скрипту, при преобразовании  

    id1234
в  

    userInfo.php?id=1234
как в комментарии @илюшка овчинников

Comment: @илюшка овчинников, к слову, это называется [ЧПУ](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%9F%D0%A3_(%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82)) (человекопонятный URL).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

**index.php**

```
 <?

 if(isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {

  if(preg_match('#id(\d+)#i',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],$matches)) {

        print_r($matches);

  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Про `vk.com/id***`: там не Apache с `.htaccess`, а nginx, и конфиг примерно так выглядит:

```
server {
    server_name vk.com;
    ...
    rewrite ^/id(\d+)$ /controllers/id.php?id=$1;
    rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z\.\-]+)$ /controllers/nickname.php?nickname=$1;
}
```

[Подробнее](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule#rewrite) про rewrite в nginx.

Comment: VK.COM использует Apache! Только он выступает в роли Back-End сервера. В роли же Front-End выступает, как вы правильно сказали, NGINX.

Comment: @Dexter: пруф? В заголовках Apache не замечен.

    Server nginx/1.2.1
    X-Powered-By PHP/5.3.3-7+squeeze3

Comment: а мне кажется, что не суть, что фактически использует ВК. Автор привел адреса лишь для примера, а сам он скорее всего только учиться веб-программированию, а значит наиболее вероятно он использует связку PHP+Apache.